# Past Coding Interview - Non-Decreasing Order

Tags: algorithm

I am doing past interviews and a question states the following: students are asked to stand in **non-decreasing order**. Find out the number of students not standing in the right place.

Seems quite simple, yet the expected output is totally different,  a few example outputs:

```
[5,1,1,3,4,1] -> 3
[4,1,2,3,4] -> 0
[4,4,3,2,1] -> 4
```

What am I not seeing right?

Comment: strikingly, the first number in each array gives the count of elements following: if excluded, the numbers to the right of the arrows give the number of elements that need to end up at a different index (ah, [Flakes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54955920/3789665) states about that).

Comment: The interviewer cannot expect you to guess the question itself!

Answer (score 1):

This question is poorly worded, and all of these answers are going to be opinion based.. That said, my only thought to make this work in any reasonable way is if the first number indicated the size of the array.

```
[5,1,1,3,4,1] -> 3
```

5 students in order `[1,1,3,4,1]`

```
unsorted     [1,1,3,4,1]
sorted       [1,1,1,3,4]
non-matching [    x,x,x]
-> 3
```

Same for the others

4 students in order `[1,2,3,4]`

```
unsorted     [1,2,3,4]
sorted       [1,2,3,4]
non-matching [       ]
-> 0
```

4 students in order `[4,3,2,1]`

```
unsorted     [4,3,2,1]
sorted       [1,2,3,4]
non-matching [x,x,x,x]
-> 4
```

Comment: I think you're missing the forest for the trees on this one - the trivial solution to an exercise like this is to keep track of the highest number you've seen and every time you get a value less than or equal to it in the list, you add one to a counter, which will keep accurate track of how many sublists you've seen which were in non-descending order.  This doesn't really answer the question as stated, as it introduces a new constraint or new flavor to the problem.

Comment: but its a better answer to what is frankly a stupidly worded question. And this one doesn't break example cases. @Makoto yours does.

Comment: I don't disagree that the wording of the question is poor, but there's nothing to suggest that the examples are perfect, either.  Interviewers could get this wrong easily and would be delighted to discover such a thing.  Besides, no one made any mention of the first number being the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that you're looking for the total length of sublists which have a sequence of descending order to identify students who aren't in the right place (since the opposite of non-descending order would literally be descending order).  Descending order also counts duplicates, so if a larger number precedes two of the same number, that sublist could also be considered to be in decreasing order.

Take the first list you provided as an example.

```
[5, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1]
```

From above, the first sublist sequence is `5, 1, 1`.  Since 5 is larger than 1, and you have a series of 1s following a larger number, the list is in descending order, and there are two students out of sequence.  The same is true for 4 and 1 as a trivial case.

The last list is a bit trickier.

```
[4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Here, we have a student ranked 4 next to another student ranked 4.  As we already established, if we have a larger number preceding two of a lesser number, the list could be seen in descending order; however, it's also the case that if a list starts with the same number and *then* decreases, that sublist is *also* in descending order.

We don't count the leading 4 since they're in an OK spot.  The following 4 would also be in an OK spot if this were a list of 2.  But since we add lesser and lesser numbers after that second 4, we determine that every element after the first one is in descending order, so we get a sublist length of 4.

Comment: This is conjecture.

Comment: `[4,1,2,3,4] -> 0` What about this case?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh:  I'd argue that it's incorrectly stated as 0, for the same reason that `[5, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1] -> 3`.  Seems like a ridiculous trick question for an interview, which are the kind that make me cringe a bit.

Comment: i agree, the question is not clear. but at the same time, a conjecture that breaks an example case, and is still iffy by counting "equal" values as failing "non decreasing" seems weird. The only way failing should be counted is if someone is standing in "decreasing" order. Why do "equal" values fail to be "non decreasing"?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh:  That's a fair point, but I'm not backing down from my statement - if you have an answer it'd be better for you to post it at this point.  As I commented in another answer (and I may just add it as an answer here) - the main thing to look for is the highest value you see at a point in the list, and count the number of values which are less than or equal to it.

Comment: I do not wish you to back down or anything. I am putting my concerns on the table.